# How can I sync the pagination with a filtering pipe in this Angular app?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pagination

I am working on a "Users app" with Angular and the [Random User API](https://randomuser.me/).

In `services/user.service.ts` I fetch the users:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  apiURL: string =
    'https://randomuser.me/api/?&results=18&inc=id,name,location';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  public getUsers(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<any[]>(`${this.apiURL}`);
  }
}
```

I use the above service in the `pagination-basic` component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from './services/user.service';
import { Countries } from './data/countries';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-pagination-basic',
  styleUrls: ['./pagination-basic.css'],
  templateUrl: './pagination-basic.html',
  providers: [UserService],
})
export class NgbdPaginationBasic {
  public page: number = 1;
  public pageSize: number = 10;
  public totalRecords: number = 0;

  public users: any[] = [];
  public countries: any[] = [];
  public country: string = '';

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  public getCountries() {
    this.countries = Countries;
  }

  public getUsers() {
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe((response) => {
      this.users = response.results;
      this.totalRecords = this.users?.length;
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCountries();
    this.getUsers();
  }
}
```

I display the users in the form of a table in `pagination-basic.html`:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="display-4">Users</h1>

  <select [(ngModel)]="country" class="form-control my-2">
    <option selected value="">Filter by country</option>
    <option *ngFor="let c of countries" [value]="c.name">{{ c.name }}</option>
  </select>

  <div *ngIf="users?.length" class="card my-3">
    <div class="card-body p-0">
      <table class="m-0 table table-striped">
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Country</th>
          <th>City</th>
        </tr>
        <tr
          *ngFor="let user of users | usersFilter: country | slice: (page - 1) * pageSize : (page-1) * pageSize + pageSize"
        >
          <td class="text-nowrap">
            {{ user.name.first }} {{ user.name.last }}
          </td>
          <td>{{user.location.country}}</td>
          <td>{{user.location.city}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="card-footer bg-white d-flex justify-content-center">
      <ngb-pagination
        size="sm"
        [pageSize]="pageSize"
        [collectionSize]="totalRecords"
        [(page)]="page"
        class="m-0"
      ></ngb-pagination>
    </div>
  </div>

  <p class="text-center" *ngIf="!users?.length">No users found! :(</p>
</div>
```

As can be observed, the results are *paginated* and *filtered by country*.

The pipe used for filtering:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'usersFilter',
})
export class UsersFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(input: any[], country: string): any[] {
    let output: any[] = [];

    if (country == '') output = input;
    else output = input.filter((user) => user.location.country == country);

    return output;
  }
}
```

There is a **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-pagination-2reemd?file=app%2Fservices%2Fuser.service.ts,app%2Fpagination-basic.ts,app%2Fpagination-basic.html)** with all the code.

#### The problem

When I filter the results by country, I get a number of results small enough that the number of pagination items should change, but it does not.

For example, I pick Canada and get *1 user*. The pagination should have one item, yet it has two. The pagination and filter are not in sync.

#### Questions

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. What is the most reliable way to sync the pagination with the filter?

Comment: You get users on init... then you are filtering the view in your ngFor according to country selection instead of getting users from the service and updating the total number of records.  You probably want to update your model when the <select> changes.  i.e. (change)="onChangeCountryFilter()"... you can then update your pagination values.  If you call the service to get users with the country filter again, you can just use a standard ngFor when displaying the users. (without slicing...)

Comment: If you always get all users first, just be sure to update this.totalRecords when filtering.  You can make a method for "updatePagination()" or something like that.

Comment: In general, when we make a table with filter and pagination, we need subscribe to a merge of the two "Observables", the change of page and the change of filter. In subscribe of this observable you call to de API. Sadly, the API you get have no capacity to filter or return the number of the elements. Some time ago (using material, but the tecnica is similar) in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63780213/connect-method-datasource-is-not-emitting-all-paginated-rows-for-mattable/63783274#63783274)

Comment: Is there a reason the StackBlitz is using Angular 6? Can the solution be in a current version?

Comment: @Meqwz I was unable to make `Ng Bootstrap` pagination in Angular 15. If you can do that, please do.

Answer (score 1):

This is because pagination works on pageSize and collection size. Your pipe here is updating the results but the variable totalRecords remains same. You have to update the totalRecords to the length of results.

If you ask for better method I suggest you to use getter function for this instead of pipe , that will be easier and simple.

1. Define getter

```
get users_data(){
 if(this.country === ''){
 this.totalRecords = this.users.length;
 return this.users;
 }
 const filtered = this.users.filter(e => e.location.country === 
 this.country);
 this.totalRecords = filtered.length;
 return filtered;
}
```

2. use getter insted of pipe

```
<tr  *ngFor="let user of users_data | slice: (page - 1) * pageSize : (page-1) * pageSize + pageSize">
```

OR if you want to fix it only by pipes you can create a function that updates totalRecords and pass it to pipe

here is the updated code of your stackblitz for pipe method :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-pagination-qynkd1?file=app%2Fpagination-basic.ts

*Still I suggest 1st method*

Comment: There should be no pagination if there are no results.

Comment: just add  *ngIf="totalRecords > 0" in div containing ngb pagination component , see my stackblitz link i have updated it.

Comment: Sorry, but it does not work ok.

Comment: Why doesn't @DarshanPatel's solution work for you?

Comment: The table should not be on the page if there are no results. Instead of "No users found! :)" should be visible.

Comment: RazvanZamfir Please clearly write your intended behaviour in question , you asked to fix pagination so i only made it work, if you also want to hide table then copy *ngif condition from pagination block to table block and not(!) condition to "no records found" block , but using variables which are changed from pipe is not recomended to use in *ngIf or *ngFor as html will be rendered too quick and frequently you'll might get "Expresion changed after checked error". use method 1 i explained in my first ans to make it work !
CC: @Meqwz

Comment: check this stackblitz link i have made changes : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-pagination-qynkd1?file=app%2Fpagination-basic.ts

but as i said pipe methods is not recomended